# Hi, i want to create a form when someone picks a option it will show the productimage

Tags: javascript, html

I am struggling with the problem that i want to create a form and show the image of the product what the customer have selected. I can't get it working so that's why i'm asking here.

At the moment i have the following code:

```
<select onchange="yesnoCheck(this);">
<option value=“luxebonbon5”>Luxe bonbons 5 stuks</option>
<option value=“luxebonbon10”>Luxe bonbons 10 stuks</option>
<option value=“luxebonbon15”>Luxe bonbons 15 stuks</option>
<option value=“bonbonmetlogo6”>Bonbons met logo 6 stuks</option>
<option value=“bonbonmetlogo12”>Bonbons met logo 12 stuks</option>
<option value=“bonbonmetlogo18”>Bonbons met logo 18 stuks</option>
<option value=“klassiekbonbon16”>Klassieke bonbons 16 stuks</option>
<option value=“klassiekbonbon23”>Klassieke bonbons 23 stuks</option>
<option value=“paasei15”>Luxe chocolade paasei 15cm</option>
<option value=“paasei20”>Luxe chocolade paasei 20cm</option>
<option value=“paashaas50”>XL chocolade paashaas 50cm</option>
<option value=“paascadeau”>Paas cadeau pakket</option>
<option value=“chocoletter”Chocoladeletter (standaard)</option>
<option value=“chocolettersmarties”>Chocoladeletter (smarties)</option>
<option value=“chocoletterhazelnoot”>Chocoladeletter (hazelnoot)</option>
<option value=“chocoletterkaramel”>Chocoladeletter (karamel zeezout)</option>
<option value=“chocoletterkoffie”>Chocoladeletter (koffiebonen)</option>
<option value=“chocoletterruby”>Ruby Chocoladeletter</option>
<option value=“chocopepernoot”>Chocolade pepernoten</option>
```

```
<div id="ifYes" style="display: none;">
<label for="car">Dit product?</label> <input type="text" id="car" name="car" /><img src=“(image)”><br />
```

```
<script>
function yesnoCheck(that) {
    if (that.value = “luxebonbon5”) {
        alert("check");
        document.getElementById("ifYes").style.display = "block";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("ifYes").style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Step 1: Fix the style of quotes you're using. `“` and `”` need to be either `"` or `'`

Comment: = is assignment, not comparison.

Comment: Are you using jQuery or plain JS?

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the part titled "Write a title that summarizes the specific problem"

Answer (score 0):

I can see two issues with your code:

1) `if (that.value = “luxebonbon5”)`: To compare two strings in JS, you use `==`, not `=`!

2) You do not need to pass a `that` parameter in your handler. Inside your event handler, `this` will always refer to the element that triggered the event, in this case the `select` element.

Now, a possible solution to your problem is having one `img` div initially, and playing on its `src` attribute whenever the user selects an option.

Assuming each option's `value` is equal to the corresponding image's name (just to make it simpler here):

```js
function yesnoCheck() {
    var image = document.getElementById("your_image_id");
    image.src = this.value;
}
```